# Is it bad to set images by drawable ID or through xml

Tags: android

I have a large amount of image views to load ( background and 80 other images). Some are buttons and some are small 10 by 10 Imageviews.  Some of the images (like 20% are referring to the same image)

Right now I just load them through xml or through the code by providing resource ID. Am I doing it wrong? Should I perhaps load them all into Bitmaps first in the memory and then set them to the View? Or maybe do the "downsampling" thing.

Please let me know if what I am doing is wrong. I am worried about Out of memory issues
Thanks

Comment: You can build an emulator which has low resources and test your app on it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not bad to set background and some images with xml or resource id code.  To do a lot of them this way is not good.

Try looking around for third party gallery libraries to help you out.  I would also recommend reading about viewpagers which holds a configurable number of pages in memory and recreates others on the fly, helping manage memory usage.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. But it the images are not displayed in gallery. They are more like buttons and sprites (ImageViews) which move around.